# PHP websocket on synology

Tags: php, websocket, nas, synology

I would like to create a chat server placed on my Nas Synology DS212J accessible by internet. I am not very competent in the field but I understood that it was necessary to use "websocket". I tried with Node.js but my nas does not allow me to install a fairly recent Node version apparently. So I am looking at "PHP Websocket".
I managed to find a code on: https: //github.com/Flynsarmy/PHPWebSocket-Chat which I deposited in the / web / chatLogPat folder of my Nas.
I managed to launch server.php in SSH but when I connect to my Chat page, **I cannot establish a connection** ... Putty (ssh) tells me all the time: "***myconnectionIp*** **has disconnected**"

Can you help me please?

Thanks a lot !!!

my link to index.html is: https://serveurarchaux.synology.me/chatLogPat

My NAS is connected to my box in: 192.168.1.12

Here are my files:

server.php on web/chatLogPat

```
    <?php
// prevent the server from timing out
set_time_limit(0);

// include the web sockets server script (the server is started at the far bottom of this file)
require 'class.PHPWebSocket.php';

// when a client sends data to the server
function wsOnMessage($clientID, $message, $messageLength, $binary) {
    global $Server;
    $ip = long2ip( $Server->wsClients[$clientID][6] );

    // check if message length is 0
    if ($messageLength == 0) {
        $Server->wsClose($clientID);
        return;
    }

    //The speaker is the only person in the room. Don't let them feel lonely.
    if ( sizeof($Server->wsClients) == 1 )
        $Server->wsSend($clientID, "There isn't anyone else in the room, but I'll still listen to you. --Your Trusty Server");
    else
        //Send the message to everyone but the person who said it
        foreach ( $Server->wsClients as $id => $client )
            if ( $id != $clientID )
                $Server->wsSend($id, "Visitor $clientID ($ip) said \"$message\"");
}

// when a client connects
function wsOnOpen($clientID)
{
    global $Server;
    $ip = long2ip( $Server->wsClients[$clientID][6] );

    $Server->log( "$ip ($clientID) has connected." );

    //Send a join notice to everyone but the person who joined
    foreach ( $Server->wsClients as $id => $client )
        if ( $id != $clientID )
            $Server->wsSend($id, "Visitor $clientID ($ip) has joined the room.");
}

// when a client closes or lost connection
function wsOnClose($clientID, $status) {
    global $Server;
    $ip = long2ip( $Server->wsClients[$clientID][6] );

    $Server->log( "$ip ($clientID) has disconnected." );

    //Send a user left notice to everyone in the room
    foreach ( $Server->wsClients as $id => $client )
        $Server->wsSend($id, "Visitor $clientID ($ip) has left the room.");
}

// start the server
$Server = new PHPWebSocket();
$Server->bind('message', 'wsOnMessage');
$Server->bind('open', 'wsOnOpen');
$Server->bind('close', 'wsOnClose');
// for other computers to connect, you will probably need to change this to your LAN IP or external IP,
// alternatively use: gethostbyaddr(gethostbyname($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']))
$Server->wsStartServer('192.168.1.12', 9300);


?>
```

index.html on web/chatLogPat

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' />
    <style>
        input, textarea {border:1px solid #CCC;margin:0px;padding:0px}

        #body {max-width:800px;margin:auto}
        #log {width:100%;height:400px}
        #message {width:100%;line-height:20px}
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="fancywebsocket.js"></script>
    <script>
        var Server;

        function log( text ) {
            $log = $('#log');
            //Add text to log
            $log.append(($log.val()?"\n":'')+text);
            //Autoscroll
            $log[0].scrollTop = $log[0].scrollHeight - $log[0].clientHeight;
        }

        function send( text ) {
            Server.send( 'message', text );
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            log('Connecting...');
            Server = new FancyWebSocket('wss://serveurarchaux.synology.me:9300');

            $('#message').keypress(function(e) {
                if ( e.keyCode == 13 && this.value ) {
                    log( 'You: ' + this.value );
                    send( this.value );

                    $(this).val('');
                }
            });

            //Let the user know we're connected
            Server.bind('open', function() {
                log( "Connected." );
            });

            //OH NOES! Disconnection occurred.
            Server.bind('close', function( data ) {
                log( "Disconnected." );
            });

            //Log any messages sent from server
            Server.bind('message', function( payload ) {
                log( payload );
            });

            Server.connect();
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id='body'>
        <textarea id='log' name='log' readonly='readonly'></textarea><br/>
        <input type='text' id='message' name='message' />
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**My question is : What should I put as host on the server.php and index.php ?
I tried "localhost", the server seems to connect but index.php seems to not connect...
I really need help !!! Pleaaaase !!**

Comment: I finally managed to get my chat to work on my Synology DS212j NAS server. The solution to the problem was to access the NAS (client) in HTTP (I created a virtualhost). I don't know if this is the right solution, but it works fine for me. I hope my question and answer will help some.